# Why doesn't product [0..] evaluate to 0 "instantly"?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to understand laziness. Because 0 multiplied with any number is 0, shouldn't `product [0..]` evaluate to 0? I tried also `foldl (*) 1 [0..]`, and to define my own product as

```
myProduct 0 _ = 0
myProduct _ 0 = 0
myProduct a b = a*b
```

Why doesn't the fold stop as soon as a 0 is found?

Comment: One can argue that it's not always the case: `foldl (*) 1 [0, undefined]`

Comment: Alternatively, how about NaN? Because, in IEEE floating-point, anything * NaN = NaN. In particular, 0 * NaN = NaN.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because the multiply operator doesn't know it's getting chained, and the fold function doesn't know the multiply operator's particular behaviour for any argument. With that combination, it needs to exhaust the list to finish the fold. In fact, for this reason [foldl](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=foldl) doesn't work at all on infinite lists. [foldr](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=foldr) does, because it can expand the function from the head of the list.

```
foldl (*) 1 [0..] -> (((..(((1*0)*1)*2)*3....)*inf
```

The outermost multiplication in the foldl case can never be found, because the list is infinite. It therefore cannot follow the chain to conclude the result is zero. It can, and does, calculate the product along the list, and that product happens to stay zero, but it will not terminate. If you use [scanl](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=scanl) instead you can see these intermediate products.

```
foldr (*) 1 [0..] -> 0*(1*(2*(3*((...((inf*1)))...)))
```

The outermost multiplication in the foldr case is found immediately, because the rest of the list is in fact left as a lazy thunk. It only runs one step:

```
foldr (*) 1 [0..] -> 0*(foldr (*) 1 [1..])
```

So because your custom multiplication operator `myProduct` is not strict in the second argument if the first argument is zero, `foldr myProduct 1 [0..]` can terminate.

As a side note, the prelude product function is restricted to finite lists (and may be implemented with foldl). Even if it used foldr, it probably would not shortcut because the standard multiply operator is strict; doing otherwise would be computationally expensive in the common case where the products are neither zero nor chained.

```
-- sum and product compute the sum or product of a finite list of numbers.

sum, product     :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum              =  foldl (+) 0  
product          =  foldl (*) 1
```

In addition, there's a reason it does not use foldr; as we could see in the expansions and scanl function, the left folds can compute as they consume the list. The right fold, if the operator does not shortcut, needs to build an expression as large as the list itself to even begin computation. This difference is because it's the innermost expression that starts the computation in the strict case, but the outermost expression that produces the result, allowing the lazy case. [Lazy vs. non-strict](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_vs._non-strict) in the Haskell wiki might explain better than I can, and even mentions that pattern matching, which you used to describe the shortcut in myProduct, can be strict.

Comment: `foldr (*) 1 [0..]` does not evaluate in one step for me. Neither does it with `myProduct`. What did I miss?

Comment: Not sure. It does for me with `myProduct`: `let myProduct a b = case (a,b) of (0,_) -> 0 ; (_,0) -> 0; (x,y) -> x*y` followed by `foldr myProduct 1 [0..]` produces 0 in ghci.

Comment: Son of a gun! If you change the order of the cases (or the patterns in the case I posted) it doesn't work any more! Any explanation for that?

Comment: Yes. The pattern matching is strict; if it has to check for `_ 0`, it must determine whether the second argument is zero or not, meaning it must be evaluated. The shortcut must be in the first pattern.

Comment: You can write a right fold that uses constant space and terminates as soon as it finds a 0. The trick is to fold a function that takes *three* arguments instead of two. Can you see how?

Comment: @dfeuer Doesn't `foldr myProduct` (using `myProduct` as defined in the question) already use constant space (well, enough space for a constant number of numbers, anyway) and terminate as soon as it finds a 0, without requiring a three-argument function?

Comment: @dfeuer I think that's a left fold though; indeed implemented with `foldr`.

Comment: @DanielWagner what if there's no 0 though? it will cause a stack explosion then, certainly not constant space operation - it forces the 2nd argument if 1st is non-zero. Similarly, if first 0 is a 100th element, it will unwind the 100 stack frames multiplying the 0 back, after finding that 100-th element, stopping the list scan, and starting the multiplications created on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch the first two lines:

```
myProduct _ 0 = 0
myProduct 0 _ = 0
myProduct a b = a*b
```

the second argument will always be evaluated before the first one and the infinite foldr won't work anymore.

Since its impossible to define a `myProduct` that works lazily for both arguments (not evaluating the second if the first is 0 and not evaluating the first if the second is 0) maybe we are better off with having `*` always evaluate both its arguments.

Comment: [Impossible, you say?](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.5/docs/Data-Unamb.html#v:pmult)

Answer (score 0):

You can have it thusly:

```
myproduct xs = foldr op id xs 1
  where
    op x r acc = if x==0 then 0 else acc `seq` r (acc*x)
```

This is a right fold that multiplies the numbers from the left, operating in constant space, and stops as soon as a 0 is encountered.